# BigQuery upload date error from csv file

Tags: date, csv, google-bigquery

I have been trying to upload a table with dates on the from a csv file but I keep getting an error about the date type like this:

```
Errors:
Too many errors encountered. (error code: invalid)
query: Invalid date: '2010-06-31' (error code: invalidQuery)
```

So it is complaining about 2010-06-31. I checked the reference and it says:

> Date type
>
> Name  Description DATE    Represents a logical calendar date. Values range
>   between the years 1 and 9999, inclusive. The DATE type represents a
>   logical calendar date, independent of time zone. A DATE value does not
>   represent a specific 24-hour time period. Rather, a given DATE value
>   represents a different 24-hour period when interpreted in different
>   time zones, and may represent a shorter or longer day during Daylight
>   Savings Time transitions. To represent an absolute point in time, use
>   a timestamp.
>
> Canonical format
>
> 'YYYY-[M]M-[D]D' YYYY: Four-digit year [M]M: One or two digit month
>   [D]D: One or two digit day

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-types#date-type

It says YYYY-[M]M-[D]D so I thought 2010-06-31 is correct but still getting an error.

My rows look like this in the csv file:

```
Regular Season,2010-06-31,Chicago,Road,22,37,21,28,,,,,108,240,39,79
```

My schema looks like this:

```
_Dataset: STRING
_DATE: DATE
_TEAMS: STRING
_VENUE: STRING
_1Q: INTEGER
_2Q: INTEGER
_3Q: INTEGER
_4Q: INTEGER
_OT1: INTEGER
_OT2: INTEGER
_OT3: INTEGER
_OT4: INTEGER
_F: INTEGER
_MIN: INTEGER
_FG: INTEGER
_FGA: INTEGER
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though June 31 exists as per [The Thirty-first of June by J.B. Priestley](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1805545.The_Thirty_first_of_June) - 
your issue can be simply just because in reality - June month has only 30 days, so load engine gets stuck with June 31st

On the other hand - query engine successfully "translates" 2010-06-31 into 2010-07-01 - try below example

```
SELECT DATE('2010-06-31')
```

Comment: Hahaha thanks very much for that. It was too late at night. I will try it again. Thanks!

Comment: sure. let us know results :o)

Comment: Yes tht fixed it, it all uploads perfectly now. thank again!

Comment: glad to hear this. thanks for update - so we know no issues with load itself :o)